# Flask JSON Validation WTForms

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-restful

I'm trying to enable flask_inputs with JSONSchema validation for a Restful API. 
The code looks like this:

```
from flask_inputs import Inputs
from flask_inputs.validators import JsonSchema

def GetValidSchema():
schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'name': {'type': 'string'}
    }
}
return schema


    class ApiResource(resource)

        class ApiInputs(Inputs):
            schema = InputsValidation.GetValidSchema() # this returns the JSON schema object 
            json = [JsonSchema(schema=schema)]

        def post(self):
            inputs =self.ApiInputs(request)
            print inputs.validate()


api.add_resource(ApiResource,'/test')
```

I really need some help as I've tried to trace out the WT-Forms but unfortunately I cannot get a clear conclusion why I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "/home/seelview/run.py", line 153, in post
    inputs.validate()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_inputs/inputs.py", line 76, in validate
    if not form.validate():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
    if not field.validate(self, extra):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 204, in validate
    stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 225, in _run_validation_chain
    validator(form, self)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing ?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the simplest complete program that still demonstrates the error. Copy-paste that entire, short program into your question. See [ask] and [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Have a look above ... That's the hole program :)

Comment: I don't think that's the whole program. At least, when I run that program, it just produces errors.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the only thing I haven't added are the flask modules and the api definition along with the run line ... You need that as well ?

Comment: Just create a basic flask minimal api add the Api Resource class and take care about GetValidSchema as that currently is called from another module ... just copy the schema object inside the ApiInputs class and should be working ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are polluting the `ApiInputs` namespace with something other than a validator. Try this instead:

```
class ApiInputs(Inputs):
    json = [JsonSchema(schema=GetValidSchema())]
```

Sample program:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_inputs import Inputs
from flask_inputs.validators import JsonSchema

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


def GetValidSchema():
    return {
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
            'name': {'type': 'string'}}}


@app.route('/')
def clickme():
    return '''
        <form action="/test" method="POST">
        <input type=submit value="Click Me" />
        </form>'''


class ApiResource(Resource):
    class ApiInputs(Inputs):
        json = [JsonSchema(schema=GetValidSchema())]

    def post(self):
        inputs = self.ApiInputs(request)
        print inputs.validate()


api.add_resource(ApiResource, '/test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! Works out of box :)